# How can I extract the Y-axis values on a graph without plotting the graph?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm working on the sample code below which creates a random walk, plots it and extracts the y-axis values. I'm looking for a way to create a list of the y-axis values, without having to plot the graph. In other words, I'm only interested to know the y-axis values.

In practice, I loop through a dataset, performing the actions below in order to extract the y_values at each given step. However, it consumes way too much memory while it's timely as well..

edit : Im only interested in the y-axis values.

Im greatful for any help on this matter!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

dims = 1
step_n = 2000
step_set = [-1, 0, 1]
origin = np.zeros((1,dims))
random.seed(30)
step_shape = (step_n,dims)
steps = np.random.choice(a=step_set, size=step_shape)
path = np.concatenate([origin, steps]).cumsum(0)
plt.plot(path)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(20, 11))
img = ax.plot(path)
plt.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=20)
y_values = ax.get_yticks() # y_values is a numpy array with your y values
```

Answer (score 1):

The Y-values are actually in `path`, so you could get these values as a list like this:

```
y_vals = [val[0] for val in path]
```

You can do this before actually having plotted the values.

Comment: Thanks! I know that the values are in in path, however I would want to extract the y-axis values :)